# IIS Website asking for user login

Tags: iis

I have an IIS Intranet application written in asp.net framework 4.  When I deploy it (by copying the files to the share on the server) everything seems to work, for me.  The only strange thing is that others get a popup that asks them to log in.  You can press cancel and the site works normally.  It works fine if I am logged in on my account, but for everyone else it asks for a login.

Any idea why that might be or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You should check that anonymous access is setup and running as an appropriate user (normally by default a local account starting IUSR_) if it is then you should check that the application files have permissions setup for that user.